# Safari OSX: overflow-y: scroll is forcing element to hide overflowing elements horizontally

Tags: css, safari, overflow

my problem is the following:

I have a div, which has a set of buttons, each one with a popup associated to him.

```
<div id="floatingFilter">
  <div class="div-1">
    <button class="popupActivator">Trigger Popup</button>
    <div class="popupContainer"><span>This is my popup.</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#floatingFilter {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.popupContainer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 190px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

When I open a popup, on Safari OSX, I can only see the first 10px of the popupContainer. The rest of it is hiddden.

Anyone had that problem/have a solution? It works in the remaining browsers.

See [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/JP3XOaoZipJxxN0dxWSN/preview)

Comment: Do you have the code on a page? I'd like to see it since I am using safari.

Comment: See this [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/JP3XOaoZipJxxN0dxWSN/preview).

Comment: could you reproduce it @PhotographyBum?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking since I thought @Vector answered it efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have `position:fixed` set. This will not allow it to scroll. If you removed this rule then it works fine.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/wtTLf/

Comment: yep, i do, but i want to have it. i need all the popups to open at the same place. but at the same time, i need the floatingFilter to be vertically scrollable. Thanks anyway.